# GET id of category and show specific columns

Tags: php, mysql

I am in the process of building out a 'cms' type application. I have the following tables:

cat_list (Categories)
doc_list(documents - these are made on the app with a WYSIWYG)
user_login (All users logins and details)

So, I am able to create the category in the app and creates a row each time time with a cat_id & cat_title.

The docs are similar with a doc_id, doc_title and cat_title (the join).

On the index page the categories are displayed, and you click into them at which point I wish to see the documents that are tied to that category listed here. I have created a JOIN to show only the list of documents which are associated to a category but I need some help with taking the ID of the category you are in and showing those docs only.

Here is the catView.php

```
        <?php
    if(isset($doc)){
    ?>

   <h1><?php echo $doc['cat_title'] ?></h1>

    <?php   
    }
    ?>

   <p><?php 

   echo '<a href="docView.php?doc_id='.$doc["doc_id"].'">'.$doc['doc_title'].'</a>' 

   ?></p>
```

I am getting to this page from my index:

```
<?php 
include 'header.php';
try{
    // Selecting entire row from doc_list table
    $results = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM cat_list ORDER BY cat_title ASC  ");

}catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

$docs = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>


 <a href="catView.php?cat_id='.$docs["cat_id"].'">Category</a>
```

And at the top of catView.php:

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>

<?php require_once '../db_con.php'; 

if(!empty($_GET['cat_id'])){
    $cat = intval($_GET['cat_id']);
try{
    $results = $dbh->prepare("SELECT cat_title, doc_list.doc_title, doc_list.id, doc_id, doc_created, doc_updated FROM cat_list, doc_list WHERE cat_id = ?");
    $results->bindParam(1, $cat);
    $results->execute();

    } catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
    }

    $doc = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    
    if($doc == FALSE){

        echo '<div class="container">';
        echo "<img src='../img/404.jpg' style='margin: 40px auto; display: block;' />";
        echo "<h1 style='margin: 40px auto; display: block; text-align: center;' />Oh Crumbs! You upset the bubba!</h1>";
        echo '<a href="userList.php"  style="margin: 40px auto; display: block; text-align: center;">Get me outta here!</a>';
        echo'</div>';
        die();
    }
}

?>
```

***UPDATE*** I can now get the A single doc from the table and doc that is associated to that category from the above, but it only shows 1 row and not all that have the cat_id assigned to them.

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong, in the `catView.php` file in the line that you have `echo '<a href="docView.php?doc_id='.$doc["doc_id"].'">'.$doc['doc_title'].'</a>' ` you want to show more than one record? is this what you want to do or when you saw _but it only shows 1 row and not all that have the cat_id assigned to them._ you mean somewhere else in your code? because your sample codes which you have provided are not well formatted and nowhere in your code, you are `selecting` on `doc_list` table.